# Remix OS for X86 - does it still exist?

Tags: remix-os

I tried to download Remix OS from http://www.jide.com/remixos-for-pc#downloadNow

The links to mirror downloads lead to a non-existent domain:
"This site can’t be reached www.support.jide.com’s server IP address could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

The Torrent links don't seem to work either - zero peers, nothing downloaded, ETA infinity.

Is there any other source for Remix OS, or is it discontinued?

Comment: Have you tried a little [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=remixos+discontinued) before asking? Just using the same terms as in your last sentence, brings a ton of results. Short answer to that last sentence: Yes. And before I'm blamed to be Vorlon: Yes to the last 3 words ;)

Comment: I did search on the torrent file name looking for another source, but the sites that came up looked sketchy, so I asked here. Now that I see it is discontinued, I'll keep searching for alternatives.

Comment: Some of the links of above search had lists of alternatives, which might be good starting points.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia says it was discontinued July 17 2017.
[Remix OS Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remix_OS)

Comment: Interesting find! I feel there was problem with the x86 version, I also use the x64 bit version of it.